# Breaking apart a String that includes last name, first name, and initial in Java

Tags: java, string

Question:

Breaking apart a String that includes last name, first name, and initial in Java.

My code:

```
    int index = 0;

    String first = "", last= "", initial= "";


    for ( int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i) == ',') {
             last = name.substring(0,i);
             index = i+1;
          }
        else if(name.charAt(i) ==' ') {
            first = name.substring(index,i);    
        }
        else if(name.charAt(i) == '.') {
            initial = name.substring(i-1, i);
        }
    }

    return (first + " " +initial+ " " + last);
}
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have spent over 5 hours trying to figure it out and need some help.

The tests seem to fail when I run.

What I am getting in the console:

```
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: eato
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: o
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Alex P Keaton)  Actual ( Alex P Keaton) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: teem
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: m
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Lois Steem)  Actual (  Steem) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: oyd,
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is a comma
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Luke A Boyd)  Actual ( Luke A.   A Boyd) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: ssen
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: n
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Lotta B Essen)  Actual ( Lotta B Essen) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: itte
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: e
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Candace B Rittenoff)  Actual ( Candace B Rittenoff) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: arly
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: y
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Stu Early)  Actual (  Early) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: eato
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: o
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Alex P Keaton)  Actual ( Alex P Keaton) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: rupt
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: t
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Vera A Bruptly)  Actual ( Vera A. A Bruptly) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: atso
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: o
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Wanda Y Datso)  Actual ( Wanda Y Datso) 
 stringReformat demo1.  the substring(1,5) is: ilve
 stringReformat demo2.  the character in position 4 is NOT a comma, it is: e
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (I O Silver)  Actual ( I O Silver) 
 finished stringReformat tests
Finished tests
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make that first sentence make sense. Also, please absolutely read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). This is not a general help forum, there are policies in place to ensure good questions stick around, and bad questions get closed. Also, this sounds like homework: that's not in itself a problem but [you need to be explicit about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Got it! Will do!

Comment: I think the question is legit anyway

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote will not pass all the tests and there is no way to fix it without changing 'how it works'. The problem is that whitespaces cannot be used for splitting or delimiting the various parts. If a string like `"Steem, Lois"` does not end with a whitespace character the method will simply return  `" Steem"` which is not correct. Also if the string ends with a `" "` after the initial dot it will include the initial inside the first name.

I provided you with two different solutions.

Suppose we have a string with the following format `"{lastname}, {firstname} {initial}."` where the initial is optional. This string is passed to the `StringFormat` method so we assume the argument is well formed.

The first solution removes whitespaces, extracts the initial if it ends with the dot and then extracts first and last name. This is all done with string manipulation.

```
public static String StringReformat(String name) {
    String initial = null, first, last;

    //Removes all whitespaces
    name = name.replaceAll("\\s", "");

    //Checks if there is initial and extracts it
    if(name.endsWith(".")) {
        initial = name.substring(name.length() - 2, name.length() - 1);
        name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 2);
    }

    //Gets first and last name
    String[] tokens = name.split(",");
    first = tokens[1];
    last = tokens[0];

    if(initial != null) {
        return first + " " + initial + " " + last;
    } else {
        return first + " " + last;
    }
}
```

The second solution uses a Matcher to check if the specified name string matches the name regex and to extract the name parts.

```
public static String StringReformat(String name) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*,\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*(?:([A-Z])\\.)?");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name.trim());
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        String last = matcher.group(1);
        String first = matcher.group(2);
        String initial = matcher.group(3);

        if(initial != null) {
            return first + " " + initial + " " + last;
        } else {
            return first + " " + last;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name argument format!");
}
```

The second solution is better and more "mantainable" but harder to understand if you are beginner.

Comment: I Went ahead and tried that out.  Thank you! But I guess my question is I am still getting 4 fails, which are:   Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Lois Steem)  Actual (  Steem) 
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Luke A Boyd)  Actual (Luke A. A Boyd) 
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Stu Early)  Actual (  Early) 
Failed  testStringReformat:  Expected: (Vera A Bruptly)  Actual (Vera A. A Bruptly)

Comment: Can you provide the format the method expects? Can you give an example of an input name string to reformat? I understand you are using ., and space to identify the name parts

Comment: The format method is the following: public static String stringReformat( String name)   and this is the example:     testStringReformat("Steem, Lois", "Lois Steem"); so the user enters the last name and middle initial if they have one.  And the output is then organized by the first name, middle initial (if they have one), and last name.   I feel like I got the code down but I am still getting 4 errors from the test.  In which I am having trouble understanding since I have spent a good amount of time already.